# Python переменная в http запросе

Tags: python, http, proxmox

Средствами библиотеки `requests` пишу запрос к `proxmox` на получение информации о состоянии контейнеров:

```
zapros1 = requests.get('https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/nodes/debprox/lxc', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в пути `https://..../node/....` являлась переменной?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В зависимости от версии python, необходимой производительности (в результатах будет указано время выполнения, замеренное при помощи timeit) и личных предпочтений можно воспользоваться одним из распространенных способов форматирования:

**1. Конкатенация:**

```
variable = 'nodes'
url = 'https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/' + variable + '/debprox/lxc'
zapros1 = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False)
```

Далее `variable` и `zapros1` не будет воспроизводиться - они везде одинаковы, меняется только `url`.

*timeit* (10000 повторений присваивания variable и url) *0.17766296499939926*.

**2. %-форматирование:**

```
url = 'https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/%s/debprox/lxc' % variable
```

*timeit 0.24981866200141667*.

**3. C помощью метода format() 1-ый вариант (начиная с python 3):**

```
url = 'https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/{}/debprox/lxc'.format(variable)
```

*timeit 0.3257489780007745*.

**4. C помощью метода format() 2-ой вариант (начиная с python 3):**

```
url = 'https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/{variable}/debprox/lxc'.format(variable=variable)
```

*timeit 0.4613359049999417*.

**5. C помощью f-строк (начиная с python 3.6):**

```
url = f'https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/{variable}/debprox/lxc'
```

*timeit 0.1394499399993947*.

**Рейтинг наиболее быстрых способов форматирования (от быстрых к медленным):**

1. C помощью f-строк.
2. Конкатенация.
3. %-форматирование.
4. C помощью метода format() 1-ый вариант.
5. C помощью метода format() 2-ой вариант.

Answer (score 4):

> как сделать так что бы в строке адреса:
>   192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/nodes/debprox/lxc вместо nodes была переменная?

воспользуйтесь форматированием строк:

```
url = "192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/{}/debprox/lxc"
r = requests.get(url.format(variable))
```